# Why applinks doesn't work on every browser?

Tags: android, intentfilter, applinks

I try to call my app on a specific url. To do that I use this intent-filter in the manifest :

```
 <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

     <data
         android:scheme="https"
         android:host="mapi.staging.mysite.com"
         android:pathPrefix="/myredirectionurl" />
 </intent-filter>
```

this do work with Google Chrome, Ecosia and Samsung Internet but don't with Xiaomi's default browser, UC Browser, CM Browser, Opera and Firefox

Comment: I think it's up to the browser how this behavior is handled. Xiaomi might just force all links to stay in the browser.

Comment: I try with the Xiaomi browser and facebook and it works :/

Comment: Facebook is probably using verified links: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations. Xiaomi's browser might only allow those.

Comment: I'm using those applinks with the assetlinks.json on my server. Everythings is working properly on other browser

Comment: I'm not sure then. You could try decompiling the Facebook APK and checking how it receives the applinks.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/RPSSample/AndroidManifest.xml
I compare to this but still don't see the problem.